# Video Chat on a website

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, videochat

I am thinking of creating a website with video chat enabled. Its a fun project a friend proposed. To be clear, I don't mean to cordinate the video chat with Google or Facebook or Skype. I want it to be run fully through my own server.

I began googling around for information and did not find a single source (I found a few here) but one source in particular I have a question about:

Farstream. http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Farstream

Farstream claims to be a unifying framework in the world of Video chat implementation (among other things).

I was wondering if anyone has experience with implementing this framework on their servers, preferably Linux servers. How they got it to work with their web site, etc?

Or, if you know Farstream is not the right answer, what software out there is known to be the best at running a video chat all from your own server?

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, video can be accomplished by using [webRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/). No plugins needed.

Slides from Google I/O is found [here](http://io13webrtc.appspot.com/#2). It contains some examples which I think is cool.